# Dart list.runtimeType should prints _GrowableList<dynamic>?

Tags: flutter, dart

such as:

```
var list = List();
print(list.runtimeType);
```

// this should prints _GrowableList but prints List
//, List is not list's actual type
// it's not consistent with map.runtimeType, map.runtimeType is the map's actual Type

```
var map = Map();
print(map.runtimeType);
```

// this prints _InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic,dynamic>, it is the map actual type.

Comment: What makes you think that it should be printing `_GrowableList`?

Comment: @Silentdoer Why do you care?  You should not depend on specific `runtimeType` values.  They will can vary from platform to platform, and the implementations for things such as `List` or `Map` could change.

Answer (score 0):

In Dart, `List` and `Map` classes instance creation provides by a factory constructor. You can find how to a collection creates in Dart Language source code [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/sdk/lib/core/list.dart) for `List` and [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/sdk/lib/core/map.dart) for `Map`. More information described in first comment for this answer.

Comment: Not quite. The standard constructor for both `List` and `Map` are marked as external factories, which means their actual implementation is platform-specific. For example, printing `List().runtimeType` in a Mac runtime will print `List<dynamic>`, whereas printing it in a dart2js context (i.e. DartPad) will print `JSArray<dynamic>`. It's possible that some platform has `_GrowableList` as the type that gets returned from the default constructor for `List`, but it's not whatever platform OP is running their test on.

Answer (score 0):

```
void main(List arguments) {
  var list= List.filled(1, 4, growable: true);
  print(list.runtimeType);
  list= List.filled(1, 4, growable: false);
  print(list.runtimeType);
}
```

my thoughts is list.runtimeType is list's actual type in runtime, so it should prints _GrowableList and _List  //(fixed length list), but in this case, it prints two List.